# System of Equations with 4 variables and 4 equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{align}
&-3x_1 &     &+x_3  &+x_4  &= 0\\
&x_1   &-x_2 &+2x_3 &      &= 0\\
&      &x_2  &-5x_3 &+2x_4 &= 0\\
&2x_1  &     &+2x_3 &-3x_4 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

I know the method of doing this by hand and can get the Reduce Row Echelon Form but even then I just get something like,

$x_1 = \frac{5}{8} x_4$

$x_2 = \frac{19}{8} x_4$

$x_3 = \frac{7}{8} x_4$

How do I solve this though? I know the ratios but I just can't seem to figure out what I'm missing. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Check your calculations – or the linear system you posted: I find the matrix of this system is invertible, so there's only the trivial solution.,

Comment: A reduced row-Echelon form should have 1 in the diagonal cells and 0 in the cells for other cells. Not the ratios you have. The reduced row-echelon form should get you the answer for each of the four variables directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your answers appear to be correct. You will not be able to find a specific answer for x4. This is because not all 4 equations are linearly independent and in this case, the 4th equation is achieved by adding together a combination of the first 3 equations. In this case, the 4th equation can be achieved: $$Equation4=-(Equation1)-(Equation2)-(Equation3)$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which means that the OP is missing one equation, for it to be 4 equations with 4 variables.